# how to use hook_webform_submission_presave on a site with multiple webforms

Tags: 6, hooks, webforms

I've got a question on the use of the hook_webform_submission_presave function for D6/webform 6.x-3.4

I've got a multi-lingual D6 site that has one webform for each language, I'm trying to create a new module that will catch the submitted form info and send it to a third party email marketing company (the forms are newsletter signups and the third party is cheetahmail).

My specific question is:
Currently I have 6 webforms on my site, and I need to send info to identify which language the signup has come from.

Do I have to write a hook for each language/form ID?
or is there a way I can set up an admin panel and list the webform IDs that I'd like to hook?

Thanks for the help, please let me know if I need to provide more detail
Steph

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I've figured this one out:

```
function cheetahmail_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
Do something here
}
```

Without calling a specific form, will effect all webforms.
in my specific instance, i'm trying to catch the submitted/validated info before it enters the DB.